# Creating php file with php code

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder if I can create a php file with php code (my project is to write a php based online poker game) and it would be nice if I could add/delete tables from php, but in order to do that I need some code to generate the php file which will be associated with that specific table. (code on every table would be the same, just need something that will allow me to create a .php file for the life time of a table). Also can you tell me how to php-delete it after wards? Thanks ahead.

Comment: You shouldn't need to generate any php files.  Instead, you can use one file to add/delete [assuming you mean database tables] tables.

Comment: I acutally meant like game tables. Gotta love English language :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this simply by having the code written to a file with

```
file_put_contents($filename, $content).
```

This will create a new file if it doesn't exist. If it exists it will truncate the file and write the new content.

To read dynamic code you could use `eval($codeString)`. This would interpret the `$codeString`as code. *NOT RECCOMENDED* because if there is *ANY* user input involved in the `$codeString`, it would be a huge security risk! (Read the WARNING below!)

To get the contents from a file, you could use `$fileContents=file_get_contents($filename)`

If you want to write to files with appending text and so on, you need to get deeper in to the php filesystem. A nice place to start is w3 schools: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_filesystem.asp

You should look at three major functions of writing to files:

```
fopen();
fwrite();
fclose();
```

### Warning!

*Reading dynamic generated code, whether it is from files or just strings, can be **really** dangerous. Especially if it gets any kind of user- or dynamic input. This is because php-files are capable of editing, creating and deleting ALOT on your server. I would recommend you to find an alternate solution!*

Comment: thank you I tried to google it and couldn't really find it, so u helped me a lot. Have a nice day and thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) Or [touch](http://php.net/touch).

`file_put_contents()` will create the file if not exists and will write provided data in to the file.
`touch()` will create the file.